Azure Document Intelligence / client.AnalyzeDocumentAsync does not work
client.AnalyzeDocumentFromUriAsync works fine.
But when I submit the stream of the exact same local file as the FileFromUri, it does not return any fields. Why is that?
    Dim invoiceUri As Uri = New Uri("https://blablabla.ch/testfile_xy.pdf")
        Dim operation As AnalyzeDocumentOperation = Await client.AnalyzeDocumentFromUriAsync(WaitUntil.Completed, "prebuilt-invoice", invoiceUri)
        Dim result As AnalyzeResult = operation.Value
        
        Dim filePath = "c:\users\myname\desktop\testfile_xy.pdf" 
        Dim stream = New IO.FileStream(filePath, IO.FileMode.Open)
        Dim operation2 As AnalyzeDocumentOperation = Await client.AnalyzeDocumentAsync(WaitUntil.Completed, "prebuilt-layout", stream)
        Dim result2 As AnalyzeResult = operation2.Value
        stream.Close()

    Debug.Print(result.Documents.Count) '1  :-)
        Debug.Print(result2.Documents.Count) '0  :-(
        

Why is no documents property transmitted?

Errors have been encountered where the AnalyzeDocumentAsync method does not return any fields when analyzing a document from a stream, while it works fine when analyzing from a URI. You can modify your code to ensure the correct stream position.

Using a URL and a local path are two different methods.
We should not use both unless we want results from both local and URL sources. The URL should be valid. For example, I use this sample URL and an Azure Storage Blob SAS URL.

With URL:
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports Azure
Imports Azure.AI.FormRecognizer
Imports Azure.AI.FormRecognizer.DocumentAnalysis
Imports Azure.AI.FormRecognizer.Models

Module Program
    Sub Main(args As String())
        MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult()
    End Sub

    Async Function MainAsync() As Task
        Dim endpoint As String = "<endpoint>" ' Replace <endpoint> with your Form Recognizer endpoint
        Dim apiKey As String = "<apiKey>" ' Replace <apiKey> with your Form Recognizer API key

        Dim client As New DocumentAnalysisClient(New Uri(endpoint), New AzureKeyCredential(apiKey))

        ' Analyzing document from URI
        Dim invoiceUri As Uri = New Uri("https://")
        Dim operation As AnalyzeDocumentOperation = Await client.AnalyzeDocumentFromUriAsync(WaitUntil.Completed, "prebuilt-invoice", invoiceUri)
        Dim result As AnalyzeResult = operation.Value

        ' Displaying results
        Console.WriteLine("Results from analyzing document from URI:")
        Console.WriteLine($"Document count: {result.Documents.Count}")
        For Each document As AnalyzedDocument In result.Documents
            Console.WriteLine($"Document of type: {document.DocumentType}")
            For Each field In document.Fields
                Console.WriteLine($"Field '{field.Key}': ")
                Console.WriteLine($"  Content: '{field.Value.Content}'")
                Console.WriteLine($"  Confidence: '{field.Value.Confidence}'")
            Next
        Next
    End Function
End Module


Output:

Without URL from Local path:
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports Azure
Imports Azure.AI.FormRecognizer
Imports Azure.AI.FormRecognizer.DocumentAnalysis
Imports Azure.AI.FormRecognizer.Models

Module Program
    Sub Main(args As String())
        Dim filePath As String = "C://Users//sample-1.pdf" ' Replace <filePath> with the actual path to your file

        If Not File.Exists(filePath) Then
            Console.WriteLine($"File not found: {filePath}")
            Return
        End If

        Dim endpoint As String = "<endpoint>" ' Replace <endpoint> with your Form Recognizer endpoint
        Dim apiKey As String = "<apiKey>" ' Replace <apiKey> with your Form Recognizer API key

        Dim client As New DocumentAnalysisClient(New Uri(endpoint), New AzureKeyCredential(apiKey))

        Using stream As New FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open)
            Dim operation As AnalyzeDocumentOperation = client.AnalyzeDocumentAsync(WaitUntil.Completed, "prebuilt-invoice", stream).Result
            Dim result As AnalyzeResult = operation.Value

            ' Add your processing logic here
            ' For example, accessing the extracted data:
            For Each document As AnalyzedDocument In result.Documents
                Console.WriteLine($"Document of type: {document.DocumentType}")

                For Each field In document.Fields
                    Console.WriteLine($"Field '{field.Key}': ")
                    Console.WriteLine($"  Content: '{field.Value.Content}'")
                    Console.WriteLine($"  Confidence: '{field.Value.Confidence}'")
                Next
            Next
        End Using
    End Sub
End Module



